# Chrome app: Why can't i modify the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

This is probably a super basic question but I cant seem to find a straight answer anywhere...

Why doesn't the `document.getElementById('pID').innerHTML = 'test';` change the text inside the p element?  also the `console.log('test');` isnt working either...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="pID">Hello, world!</p>
</body>
</html>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(onLoad);

function onLoad() {
 chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {          
    'bounds': {
    'width': 400,
    'height': 900
    }
 });
}
```

MANIFEST.JSON:

```
{
"name": "Hello World!",
"description": "My first Chrome App.",
"version": "0.1",
"app": {
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
}
}
```

MAIN.JS:

```
function onLoad() {
  console.log('test');
  document.getElementById('pID').innerHTML = 'test';
}
window.onload=onLoad;//This is what I was missing!
```

@rshanchez:  I changed it and i get the following error (still doesnt work):

*Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

@rshanchez: I made the window.onload=onLoad; and that did it.  Thanks for the help!  If you want the rep points answer the question and i'll mark it as answered... Otherwise +1 to awesomeness for you!

Comment: Your script is running in the background page, so the `document` object you are accessing is that of the background page. To manipulate the `window.html` document, you need to include a script from your `window.html` file using a `<script src="xxx.js">` tag.

Comment: @rsanchez: Your comment, albeit correct, is a little bit one-sided. One can also access and modify the window.html's document here by providing a callback argument for the chrome.app.window.create() call, which should look like function(win), and using win.contentWindow.document in its body.

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko you're totally right, thanks!

Comment: @Dave I tested with your files and didn't get the error you mention. As @sowbug mentions, you are now missing a `window.onload=onLoad;` at the end of `main.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody is calling your function called "onLoad." Perhaps you want window.onload (be careful about the capitalization; close doesn't count).